# BeginExecuteReader Error in WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I'm trying to connect to database asynchronously in WCF service. But despite of setting "Asynchronous Processing=true" in connection string I'm getting

> `System.InvalidOperationException` with message `BeginExecuteReader:
>   Connection property has not been initialized.`

The code I'm using to connect to database is:

```
public void Connect()
{
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=User12-PC; Initial Catalog = BMS;  User Id=sa; Password = pass; Asynchronous Processing=true"))
   {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
      command.CommandText = "Select l.currvalue from" +
                            " advt_ctrl_pts as p inner join advt_log_in_ctrl_pts l" +
                            " on p.registerid = l.regid and p.ddcid = l.ddcid" +
                            " where p.pointid = 5156102" +
                            " order by datetime";

      command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

      conn.Open();
      IAsyncResult result = command.BeginExecuteReader(); //This part is returning exception
      if (result.IsCompleted)
      {
         timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(onTimerTick), command.EndExecuteReader(result), 5000, 5000);
      }
   }
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you did not assign connection to command:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
```